# Javascript results to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Q1: My point is create many buttons as many rows of array. Like this, only one button appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = [];

$('#button').click(function(){

var value1 = $('#value1').val();
var value2 = $('#value1').val();
var value3 = $('#value1').val();
var newArray = []; 
var newArray[0] = value1;
var newArray[1] = value2;
var newArray[2] = value3;
myArray.push(newArray);

$("#save").append(
    $("<button>").click(function() {
        myFunction.apply(null, myArray);
    }).text("Click me!")
   );
   });

});

function myFunction(value1,value2,value3)
{
var jsonData = $.ajax({
url: "file.php?value1=" + value1 + "&value2=" + value2 + "&value3=" + value3
dataType: "json",
async: false
}).responseText;
(...)
}
//edited: problem maybe found. I said buttons dont do anything because of this.
OUTPUT: file.php?value1=paul,23,USA&value2=undefined&value3=undefined
//it seems that value1 gets all values :s
</script>


<div id ="save"></div>
```

Im looking for a solution that return someting like this:

eg:

```
<!--<button onclick="myFunction(name,age,country)">Click me</button>-->
<button onclick="myFunction(paul,23,USA)">Click me</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(john,23,USA)">Click me</button>
```

EDITED MY CODE WITH MORE DETAILS

Comment: Why mix jQuery and inline JS? Bad idea IMO...Seems like you're missing some necessary jQuery concepts there... I suggest you start here http://jqfundamentals.com/, from scratch. Bad habits are hard to quit.

Comment: first try .append() instead of .html(). I'm pretty sure .html() replaces where .append() adds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.html` replaces, and your quotes are mismatched. But it doesn't matter - jQuery is better at manipulating the DOM than it is at manipulating strings. Try:

```
$("#save").append(
    $.map(myArray, function(item) {
        return $("<button>").click(function() {
                   myFunction.apply(null, item);
               }).text("Click me");
    })
);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/uddsr/2/)

Comment: I understande that, but it doesnt fit my needs . Because I need to give to myFunction() some values that are stored in myArray to have an output like this: eg. `myFunction(john,23,USA)` or `myFunction(name,age,country)`, for that the only approach that worked was `myFunction(\''+myArray[i].join("','")+...)`

Comment: The `item` in the function given to `map` is the element in the array. You can just read properties off of it. `myFunction(item.name, item.age, item.country)`

Comment: Ive tried it in my website but buttons doesnt seem to do anything. Click and nothing happens. this is the aspect of my function: `myFunction('','','','',',,,')`, `myArray[0] = ('paul','35','USA','NY','1,2,3,4')`

Comment: @skdnewbie: `myArray[0]` cannot `= ('paul','35','USA','NY','1,2,3,4')`. That'll just make it `'1,2,3,4'`. Use an array: `['paul','35','USA','NY','1,2,3,4']`

Comment: @minitech, I will update my code with full code, because its not working  atm :s ok?

Comment: @skdnewbie: Oh, okay :D For that, you have to combine both of them. Updated one last time. (Hopefully.)

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this:

```
    <div  id="save">
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addButtons(){
            for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
            {
                var button = $('<button id="btn_'+i+'" onclick="myFunction(this);">Click me</button>')
                $(button).data('details',myArray[i]).appendTo("#save");
            }
        }
        function myFunction(element){
            alert($(element).data('details'));
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: hmm, could you explain that?

Comment: @skdnewbie: Strings are the problem. jQuery is a library built specifically to manipulate the DOM, so adding everything to a big string mostly defeats its point. (Not to mention that DOM manipulation is faster than HTML manipulation, that it's less error-prone, and that the event handler works with all kinds of data - not just strings.)

Comment: @skdnewbie jQuery lets you control things at a higher level of abstraction than just string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

You're only seeing one button because the `.html()` method *replaces* the html of the element. It doesn't append.

Luckily, jQuery has a method for the behavior you want, fittingly called `append`. Change it to look like this:

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
  var button = $("<button>Click me</button>");
  $("#save").append(button) ;
}
```

I intentionally left the onclick behavior out of that snippet. You can write it in the html of the button you create, as you have been, or you can do it with jQuery - the second method is preferable, and would look like this:

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
  var button = $("<button>Click me</button>")
               .click(function(){
                    // call the actual function you want called here
               });
  $("#save").append(button);
}
```

Comment: Ill try your approach :) seems very nice!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are replacing the html in the `$("#save")` in the loop . Try
`$("#save").append("<button onclick="myFunction('"+myArray[i]+"')">Click me</button>") ;`

Comment: This was my first try. It worked but i dont know why is creating duplicated buttons, maybe something wrong with my arrays. edit: Im seems not, because Akhil solution did it right

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    //Create a new DOM button element ( as jQuery object )
    // Set the current button index, and add the click action
    var button = $('<button />').data('myindex', i).click(function(){
        var myArrayItem = myArray[$(this).data('myindex')];
        alert(myArrayItem);
    }).html('My label n. '+i);
    $('#save').append(button)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bothering with all the JQuery and complicated code, just use simple way to implement this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var myArray = ["New York", "Boston", "San Jose", "Los Angeles"];

    var strHTML = "";
    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
    {
        strHTML += "<button onclick='myFunction("+i+")'>Click me</button>";
    }       

    $("#save").innerHTML = strHTML;

    function myFunction(index)
    {
        alert(index);
        // do your logic here with index
    }
</script>
```